# How to fix 'Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator'?

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin

The problem occurs when I install the latest version(5.2.0) of phpmyadmin using docker.

**Install Command**

```
$ docker run --name myadmin -d -e PMA_HOST=dbhost -p 8080:80 phpmyadmin
```

**Docker Info**

```
Server Version: 20.10.17 
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core) 
OSType: linux 
Architecture: x86_64
```

If I change the version of phpmyadmin to 4.9.6 there will be no problem.

---

**Docker Info**

```
Server Version: 19.03.8 
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core) 
OSType: linux 
Architecture:x86_64
```

There is no problem installing the latest version on the above environment.I don't know if it is because the Kernel version is too low, but the Kernel version is not allowed to be modified. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Which Docker image are you using, and how do you install phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

It is the reason of **Apache web server**.It requires a higher Linux kernel version.

We can fix it by **upgrading the kernel version** or **using a phpmyadmin image of a lower version Apache web server**

Please see https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/issues/373